# Why do I get an invalid path when I try and construct a JPQL join query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, inner-join, jpql

I’m using JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, and MySQL 5.5.37.  How do I write a JPQL query that does a join?  I’m trying below

```
    final String jpqlQuery = "SELECT m FROM Message m LEFT JOIN MessageReadDate mr " + 
            " INNER JOIN m.group g " + 
            " LEFT JOIN g.classroom c " + 
            " LEFT JOIN c.ROSTER u WHERE " + 
            " u.USER = :recipient AND " + 
            " u.ENABLED = 1 AND " + 
            " c.ENABLED = 1 AND " + 
            " g.NAME = '' AND " +
            " m.author <> :author";
    Query query = m_entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery);
```

but getting the error “Path expected for join! … Invalid path: 'g.classroom'”.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
 Path expected for join!
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:379)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3903)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3689)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.mainco.subco.messaging.repo.MessageDaoImpl.getUnreadClassAnnouncements(MessageDaoImpl.java:161)
        at org.mainco.subco.messaging.repo.MessageDaoImpl.getUnreadMessages(MessageDaoImpl.java:140)
        at org.mainco.subco.messaging.repo.MessageDaoIT.testGetUnreadMessages(MessageDaoIT.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:  74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    [ERROR]: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 'g.classroom'
    [ERROR]: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 'g.classroom'
     Invalid path: 'g.classroom'
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.lookupConstant(LiteralProcessor.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:225)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3903)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3689)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    …
```

My message entity is as follows …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg")
public class Message
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE", columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private Group group;
```

And my group entity is as follows …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg_group")
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASSROOM_ID", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private Classroom classroom;
```

So why can’t I reference the “classroom” attribute?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue reported by Hibernate is in the first row:

```
final String jpqlQuery = "SELECT m FROM Message m LEFT JOIN MessageReadDate mr "...
```

in the LEFT JOIN statement. In **hql**, the JOIN must be expressing the relation, e.g.

```
LEFT JOIN m.MessageReadDate mr // the m is referencing the MessageReadDate
```

If there is no reference, we can still use that, but with Cartesian product

```
FROM Message m, MessageReadDate mr
```

in that case, the CROSS JOIN will be issued

See the:

- [16.2. The from clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-from)

*small cite:*

> Multiple classes can appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter
from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

- [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins)

> You can also assign aliases to associated entities or to elements of a collection of values using a join. For example:

```
from Cat as cat
    inner join cat.mate as mate
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use JOIN's in HQL then you have to use it only on the properties of the class which is mentioned in `From` clause.

What it means is, in this particular line:

```
SELECT m FROM Message m LEFT JOIN MessageReadDate mr
```

hibernate checks if `MessageReadDate` is defined as a property in `Message` class which is considered as path here. As there is nothing called `MessageReadDate` it throws an exception.

So to fix this issue, add the required property for `MessageReadDate` class in `Message` class, lets say `mrd` (you can have your relation as one-to-one or on-to-many or etc) and then use the query like this:

```
SELECT m FROM Message m LEFT JOIN m.mrd
```

in this way we are telling hibernate how to join the message with its corresponding properties so the path for join is clear to hibernate.